# Rails error: Wrong number of arguments(given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

I am obtaining the error message `wrong number of arguments(given 1, expected 0)` from the controller for the app's dashboard:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  
  def index
    @tweets = Tweet.order(created_at: :desc).map { |tweet| TweetPresenter.new(tweet) }
  end
end
```

I do not know why it would be expecting 0 arguments.

The model for the tweets is arranged so:

```
class Tweet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { maximum: 280}
end
```

I'll explain the logic of what follows after the controller, just in case it is relevant to the issue (although it is downstream from the controller, and so I could not guess that would be relevant)

The controller sends the `@tweets` instance variable to the pertinent view, that is `views/dashboard/index`, and is used thus:

```
    <%= render partial: "tweets/tweet", collection: @tweets, as: :tweet_presenter %>
```

From there, the `@tweets` are passed on as a collection to be processed by the `tweet_presenter`

```
class TweetPresenter
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

  def Initialize(tweet)
    @tweet = tweet
  end

  attr_reader :tweet

  delegate :user, :body, to: :tweet

  def created_at
    if(Time.zone.now - tweet.created_at) > 1.day
      tweet.created_at.strftime("%b %-d")
    else
      time_ago_in_words(tweet.created_at)
    end
  end

end
```

And finally at the view `tweets/tweet` the tweets are displayed

```
  <div class="tweet py-3 px-2 border-bottom">

    <div class="d-flex flex-row">  
      <div class="me-2">
        <%= image_tag tweet_presenter.user.avatar, size: "40x40", class: "rounded-circle" %>
      </div>
      <div>
          <p class="mt-2"><%= tweet_presenter.user.display_name %> @<%= tweet_presenter.user.username %> . <%= tweet_presenter.created_at %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <p class="mb-0"><%= tweet_presenter.body %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `def Initialize` is capitalized, should be lowercase `def initialize`

Comment: Thank you so much @Alex. That took care of the issue. I can't believe I spent an entire day looking for it and could not find it.